# SQL - What is the real danger of SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> **NOTE:** This is not a question about what *is* [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection), but rather a question to clear up what the actual vulnerability, particularly given some specific test cases.
>
> **Background:** Please see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnQIbyK779I) by a group called *Modern Rouge*. Or, you can ignore it, as it's kind of oversimplified for people who don't have technical skills and aren't already familiar with [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). I will point our the important part when it's needed.

So, for those who don't know what SQL Injection is (I'm just adding this for completeness and to give background to my particular question), Let's say I have PHP code like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
```

This code is vulnerable because let's say a malicious end user puts in their username as `' or 1=1;--`, this could make the final query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' or 1=1;--'
```

Which does not have the intended effect.

So, now watch the video around [the 4:00 mark](https://youtu.be/KnQIbyK779I?t=240).

The example they give on their test website for SQL injection, they use SQL injection to bypass the password check.

Here's what I don't get, In real life, wouldn't I check the password in PHP instead, making this specific example useless? For example:

```
if($userRecordFromDB["pwd"] == $pwd) { // User authenticated.
```

Am I right that SQL injection can't bypass my PHP authentication? What is the vulnerability here? Unless I'm tying the password check to my query (which I'll admit could have been done for the example), even if I have a vulnerable query, my site shouldn't be vulnerable.

Second related question: The video goes on to imply that a single vulnerability could allow attacker access to my whole db! I'm assuming they mean an attacker could do something like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' or 1=1; SELECT * FROM creditInformationTable where 1=1--'
```

`$username` of course would be `' or 1=1; SELECT * FROM creditInformationTable where 1=1--`

However, this also confuses me. Unless I put this data into a nice table or something for them, wouldn't the data never leave the back-end, even if the query was vulnerable? How could they possibly get this information unless I give it to them inadvertently?

Which leads me to the bigger question: What is the danger of SQL injection? Is it purely theoretical, or are there real cases where an attacker could do something like login or access all the tables in your DB from pure SQL injection?

**Edit:** Scratch all that. Let me narrow a bit.

How does it leave the back-end? Even if something queries the wrong thing, how would my attacker get it? DB APIs like PDO and SQLI return the information to PHP, **NOT** the resulting page. Shouldn't a well written PHP script catch that wrong data is there, or, at the very least, not echo it all out to the user?

Comment: `Here's what I don't get, In real life, wouldn't I check the password in PHP instead` if you built it right, the real problem is when someone queries for a hashed password as well, then a simple `$username = "' OR 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0 --"` would allow someone to iterate though your DB table to any user they chose.  The `--` is the start of a comment in SQL and nullifies the rest of the query.

Comment: Even without that, it's possible to expose data that otherwise would be private to a user account, such as billing information, Personal data etc...

Comment: But how? I'm still a tad confused because in this example, shouldn't it still never leave the backend?

Comment: For example say you have some way to review account data, A user could use his existing account and a SQL vulnerability to display this data from another users account.  Just because they need a valid Username doesn't mean you can always trust what they do.

Comment: It's also a matter of risk VS reward,  you risk nothing by preparing all your queries.  By not doing it you risk data breaches, lawsuits, legal action, lack of trust in your Brand etc.  It's just not worth it when there is a clear way to avoid such things.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Ah. a light went off. That makes sense. And, I agree that prepared statements is a very simple solution that makes you risk nothing. My thing is, that apparently I'm still really stuck on, I'm still not understanding how it leaves the back-end. Maybe I should give it a break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL injection is not theoretical. There are news reports about real-world data breaches perpetrated using SQL injection practically every month. There's a great site that collects them: https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/

Here's a good one from last month:

https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/vba5nb/fornite-login-hack-epic-games-website

> **Bugs on Epic Games Site Allowed Hackers to Login to Any ‘Fortnite’ Player’s Account**
>
> ...
>
> That page, which is now offline, contained two vulnerabilities that are often found in websites: an SQL Injection (or SQLi), and a Cross-Site Scripting (or XSS), according to Check Point researchers.

Regarding the examples you give, I do recommend validating the password in the application code. Then you can differentiate between "no account found" vs. "account found, but password was wrong" (you don't want to reveal this to the user, but you might want to log the error, and possibly lock the account if they have too many failed password attempts).

But regardless, the SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL injection. Not only with the "OR 1=1" trick that you show, but also if you can trick the query into running UNION-based SQL queries:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES -- '";
                                              ^^ $username ...
```

If the attacker can find an SQL query in your app (not necessarily the search by account name), they can use this technique to query all your tables. Then they can further use UNION techniques to query the data in all the tables, once they know their names.

---

Regarding your follow-up question:

*"How does the data leave the back-end?"*

Consider if your password-checking code (for the query above) looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, username, password_hashed FROM users WHERE username='$username'";

$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
  if (!password_verify($password, $row['password_hashed'])) {
    die("Invalid login for user {$row['username']}");
  }
}
```

See? The result from the SQL query is output to the user. To the developer of this code, it seems obvious that since they just queried for `$username` then that's the value that would be returned by the query. They feel that `$row['username']` is safe to use.

But it's not — it's some data from the other part of the UNION. By using CONCAT() and GROUP_CONCAT(), the attacker can even put together multiple columns from multiple rows. *And they do.* It may take them several tries to get their attack query to have the right number of columns in the right positions, but they apparently have nothing better to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm still confused on is how does it leave the back-end like this? Even if it does get queried, how can the attacker find it if it's only the PHP should theoretically see it?

Comment: An example using the UNION would be renaming the fields to match those of the user table, does a hacker really care what the field is named, they can do `UNION ALL SELECT cc_number AS username ....` etc.  Obviously you shouldn't keep CC number but that's not the point.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - they don't even need to alias the columns of their UNION SELECT. The column names don't make any difference in a UNION, they are defined by the *first* SELECT, and ignored in subsequent SELECTs.

Comment: I meant by renaming fields they can make a search form, for example spit out data it's not supposed to.  The application likely won't know the difference between the value of any given string, so if you display something like `username` (or any field) there is no guarantee that they won't just rename a field `username` (or whatever) to get the output.  Specifically this `How does it leave the back-end? Even if something queries the wrong thing, how would my attacker get it?`

Comment: Bingo. I understand now. Thanks. That's what I needed to understand. +1 and accept. Shout out to @ArtisticPhoenix too for your hard work and help too.

Comment: I work in a High Security environment,  the whole SSAE 16, DMZ, kind of stuff....  So I try to stay up on this stuff, like Directory Transversal attacks, SQL attacks , XSS  etc...  We actually even use a security consultant to attack our sites, do our disaster recovery stuff, document our processes, means of encryption etc...  It's complicated stuff, easy to get overwhelmed.

Comment: The biggest thing is never trust your inputs, its like saying,  You give me this brick of gold, and I'll put it in a room with this other guys 2 bucks, and then give that guy the key and what should I tell you if your brick of gold walks off.  Well I trusted this other guy and he took it.  That is just not going to cut it.